# How do I initialize thread primitives from a multithreaded context with win32?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading

I want to create a static Lock

```
void foo(){
    static CRITICAL_SECTION *lock = NULL; //this is the problem, I cannot create any primitive to do this with win32 threads
    static long isInitialized = 0;
    if (InterlockedExchange(&isInitialized, 1) == 0){ //this will ensure that lock is initialized only once
        lock = (CRITICAL_SECTION*)malloc(sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION));
        InitializeCriticalSection(lock);
    }
    EnterCriticalSection(lock); //this might be called before initialization is done...YIKES!
    ...
    LeaveCriticalSection(lock); 
}
```

How do I initialize the lock from a multithreaded context?

A crappy solution could look like:

```
void foo(){
    static CRITICAL_SECTION *lock = NULL; //this is the problem, I cannot create any primitive to do this with win32 threads
    static long isInitialized = 0;
    static volatile long isInitializeDone = 0;
    if (InterlockedExchange(&isInitialized, 1) == 0){ //this will ensure that lock is initialized only once
        lock = (CRITICAL_SECTION*)malloc(sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION));
        InitializeCriticalSection(lock);
        isInitializeDone = 1;
    } else {
        while (isInitializeDone == 0){

        }
    }
    EnterCriticalSection(lock); //this might be called before initialization is done...YIKES!
    ...
    LeaveCriticalSection(lock); 
}
```

but is there a better solution?

Comment: If at all possible, avoid the problem by initializing each primitive before you start more than one of the threads that will use that primitive for synchronization.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631879/library-initialization-pthread-once-in-win32-implementation#633121) and [one of its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/633121/1535516).

Comment: @xaizek that would have been perfect if i didnt have the requirement to support windows xp

Comment: You realize than in the code as shown you're not allocating any memory for the critical section?  Also, you should be passing a pointer to the critical section to InitializeCriticalSection, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yea, it was a typo. fixed it though.

Comment: If you have to support XP, and can't use C++, and can't initialize the critical section ahead of time, then for most scenarios I think the code you've posted is probably just about as good as can be done.  The only thing I'd suggest is that you call `Sleep(0)` in the loop waiting for `isInitializeDone` rather than spinning the CPU.  (Or, if there are likely to be many threads waiting in this way, use an event object.)

Comment: (On second thoughts using an event object isn't likely to be sensible; scratch that.)

Answer (score 2):

If this is C++, you can call a function to initialize that critical section:

```
static CRITICAL_SECTION *lock = get_critical_section();
```

like

```
CRITICAL_SECTION* get_critical_section()
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION *lock = NULL;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&lock);
    return lock;
}
```

C++ specifies that exactly one thread will initialize that thing, and that all other threads will wait for it:

#### [stmt.dcl]

*If control enters
the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for
completion of the initialization.*

EDIT: I don't know since when the text within the standard is like this, but I'm pretty sure this is what all implementations do.

Comment: what standard is this? and is it also true for c?

Comment: No, this works only in C++, my copy of the standard is from like half a year ago. In C you are out of luck.  You can download the latest draft of the C++ standard [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to take advantage of the fact that every process has a default heap with an associated lock that will already be initialized:

```
void foo(void)
{
    static CRITICAL_SECTION lock;
    static DWORD lock_status = 0;

    if (lock_status == 0)
    {
        HANDLE process_heap = GetProcessHeap();
        if (!HeapLock(process_heap)) fail();

        if (lock_status == 0)
        {
            InitializeCriticalSection(&lock);
            lock_status = 1;
        }

        if (!HeapUnlock(process_heap)) fail();
    }
    EnterCriticalSection(&lock);
    // ...
    LeaveCriticalSection(&lock);
}
```